# How to pass div data from one page to another page

Tags: jquery

I have a set of checkboxes inside my div , i want to move all these values to another page

I tried this way

Right now this div is static , but it will contain values which will be genearted dynamically .

Page1.html

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var obj = [];
    var elems = $("#one");
    $(document).ready(function(){
    });
    function onsubmit()
    {
    for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        var id =document.getElementById('value');
        alert(id);
        tmp = {
            'values': id
        };
        obj.push(tmp);
    }
    return true;
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form onsubmit="myFunction()" action="page2.html" method="get">
    <div id="one"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">I have a car <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I have a blank page2.html

Dont know how to proceed further , could anybody please help ??

Answer (score 0):

You're sending the variables to page2.html through a query string since you're using the get method.

The query string is going to look something like

```
yourdomeain.com/page2.html?vehicle=Bike
```

Then you need to pull those values out of the query string in page2.html.

Comment: The data can be huge , so i cant go for this , infact im thinking of creating a json and then pass that .

Comment: JSON will be just as huge.

Answer (score 0):

use php to get values on other page with $_GET or $_REQUEST
you also need to change you names on the input to not be duplicated

```
<input type="checkbox" name="bike" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="car" value="Car">I have a car <br>

<?php

    $bike = $_GET['bike']
    $car = $_GET['car']

?>
```

Comment: Thank you , but I am not using php

Comment: ok check this out then it may help you out
http://smallbusiness.chron.com/populate-text-fields-url-variables-51862.html

Answer (score -1):

Try to use.

```
var div = $('yourdiv').serialize();
```

To pass the value you should use POST or GET, so you can serialize your div, then you can submit or just redirect or any other way to pass the value.

ex.

```
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com"+div;
```

Comment: In first page or in second page ??

Comment: I have tried the way you mentioned , http://jsfiddle.net/wfDYE/ , but the alert is not getting fired . any idea why ??

Comment: You need `?` between the filename and parameters.

Comment: Your fiddle defines a function called `onsubmit`, but the HTML calls `myFunction`.

Comment: You also need to use one of the `No wrap` options so that the function will be in the global scope.